# Django Broken Pipe Error

Tags: django, broken-pipe

I am running an app in Django, and get the following error on my local runserver terminal:

```
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[31/Dec/2015 20:32:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 141859
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 215, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.33.1', 4507)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread

    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/hellobands/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/c
ore/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

I am completely stumped at where to start trying to fix this; has anyone seen this error type before? Where would I start trying to debug this?

Comment: Are you seeing any problems other than this error on your console? Possibly your browser just closed the connection before Django’s development server expected it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client (probably your web browser) closed the connection before Django’s development server expected it to. The error message is harmless, though untidy, and won’t occur in production, only on the development server.

These errors were suppressed in [a patch to Django 13 months ago](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9253042d53d61b23b3f727a00c41e8089be73836), so you can probably make them go away by upgrading to a newer release of Django.